# Como ignorar certos elementos em uma lista que passará por um processo randômico? (pendente)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Esse programa encontra quadrados mágicos 3x3 por força bruta e imprime automaticamente quando encontra um.

código:

```
import random

vetor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def magicsquare():
    return vetor[0]+vetor[1]+vetor[2]==\
           vetor[3]+vetor[4]+vetor[5]==\
           vetor[6]+vetor[7]+vetor[8]==\
           vetor[0]+vetor[3]+vetor[6]==\
           vetor[1]+vetor[4]+vetor[7]==\
           vetor[2]+vetor[5]+vetor[8]==\
           vetor[0]+vetor[4]+vetor[8]==\
           vetor[2]+vetor[4]+vetor[6]

while not magicsquare():
    random.shuffle(vetor)

print (vetor)
```

O programa funcionando no repl:

https://repl.it/@William33/ComposedFirstArachnid

Não estou conseguindo fazer a determinada função:

Sabendo que em um quadrado mágico `3x3`, o número `5` sempre estará no meio, eu gostaria de já deixa-lo no meio, ou seja, ele já está, mas na hora que o programa faz o "random" gostaria que não mexesse no número `5`, não mudasse ele de lugar...

Pelo simples fato que, para encontrar um quadrado mágico `3x3` com `9` números, as possibilidades são `362880` sendo assim o fatorial de `9`...

Então se praticamente eu já deixei o número `5` no lugar.. passarão apenas `8` números pelo "random" e as possibilidades serão somente `40320` que seria o fatorial de `8`.

Agora imagina em um quadrado `4x4` com `16` números...

As possibilidades são 20 trilhões ou seja, `20922789888000` mas, se eu pudesse, já deixar `4` números nos locais certos que não passassem pelo "random", eu teria apenas `12` números diminuindo as possibilidades para 479 milhões, ou seja `479001600`.

A velocidade para encontrar os quadrados mágicos aumentaria drasticamente...

Agora a pergunta:

Como ignorar certos elementos em uma lista que passará por um processo randômico?

***(Continuação)***

O código com as implementações em `3x3` funciona perfeitamente.. mas com `4x4` não está funcionando segue o código:

```
 import random

 vetor = [4, 14, 15, 1, 9, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16]

 def shuffle(vetor, frozen_vetor):        
 frozen = [(pos, item) for (pos,item) in enumerate(vetor) if item in 
 frozen_vetor]    
 random.shuffle(vetor)    
 for pos, item in frozen:
     index = vetor.index(item)
     vetor[pos], vetor[index] = vetor[index], vetor[pos]    

 def magicsquare():
     return vetor[0]+vetor[1]+vetor[2]+vetor[3]==\
            vetor[4]+vetor[5]+vetor[6]+vetor[7]==\
            vetor[8]+vetor[9]+vetor[10]+vetor[11]==\
            vetor[12]+vetor[13]+vetor[14]+vetor[15]==\
            vetor[0]+vetor[4]+vetor[8]+vetor[12]==\
            vetor[1]+vetor[5]+vetor[9]+vetor[13]==\
            vetor[2]+vetor[6]+vetor[10]+vetor[14]==\
            vetor[3]+vetor[7]+vetor[11]+vetor[15]==\
            vetor[0]+vetor[5]+vetor[10]+vetor[15]==\
            vetor[3]+vetor[6]+vetor[9]+vetor[12]


while not magicsquare():
    shuffle(vetor, [4, 14, 15, 1, 9])

print (vetor)
```

Percebe que eu usei `5` números já na ordem do quadrado mágico, ignorando eles..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então sobrariam apenas `11` números para o "random", que dariam `39916800` possibilidades... e encontraria o quadrado mágico super rápido... mas o programa está demorando muito para encontrar o quadrado.. então provavelmente ele está usando os `16` no "random" que dariam `20922789888000` possibilidades.. ou então deve ter algum outro erro no programa..

Comment: Assim, a pergunta aparenta estar bem redigida, auto-explicativa, mas o título dela foi meio estranho para mim. Parece que ela é auto-suficiente, então esse título com "(continuação)" me chamou atenção negativamente... se tiver outra ideia para título, não atrairá olhares negativos...

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma é você criar o seu próprio **shuffle** ignorando os elementos desejados:

```
def shuffle(items, frozen_items):        
    frozen = [(pos, item) for (pos, item) in enumerate(items) if item in frozen_items]    
    random.shuffle(items)    
    for pos, item in frozen:
        index = items.index(item)
        items[pos], items[index] = items[index], items[pos]

    return items
```

Não parece muito pythônico mas é uma forma de ignorar itens ao fazer um shuffle.

Ex:

```
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print shuffle(vector, [8, 9]) // mantém os números 8 e 9 na posição original
```

Você pode adaptar pra ignorar o index ao invés do número.

**EDIT**

Para usar no seu código, mantendo a utilização da variável **vetor** por referência:

```
import random

vetor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def shuffle(vetor, frozen_vetor):        
    frozen = [(pos, item) for (pos,item) in enumerate(vetor) if item in frozen_vetor]    
    random.shuffle(vetor)    
    for pos, item in frozen:
        index = vetor.index(item)
        vetor[pos], vetor[index] = vetor[index], vetor[pos]    

def magicsquare():
    return vetor[0]+vetor[1]+vetor[2]==\
           vetor[3]+vetor[4]+vetor[5]==\
           vetor[6]+vetor[7]+vetor[8]==\
           vetor[0]+vetor[3]+vetor[6]==\
           vetor[1]+vetor[4]+vetor[7]==\
           vetor[2]+vetor[5]+vetor[8]==\
           vetor[0]+vetor[4]+vetor[8]==\
           vetor[2]+vetor[4]+vetor[6]

while not magicsquare():
    shuffle(vetor, [5]) # ex: mantém o número 5 na posição original

print vetor
```

Comment: Obrigado Tom, mas como que ficaria no código? essas implementações??

Comment: Editei com a utilização no seu código, não sei se é bem isso que você quer...Existem outros algoritmos mais eficientes que, dado um NxN, ele  **gera um quadrado mágico**

Comment: Eu testei aqui e não funcionou apareceu isso: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23
    shuffle(vetor, [5]) // ex: mantém o número 5 na posição original
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: comentário nessa linha está errado...troquei # por //

Comment: Opa blz acho que agora deu certo sim !!!

Comment: Tipo acho que não deu certo.. pq tentei aqui com 4x4.. e está demorando pra fazer o quadrado sendo que não demoraria, acho que a "função" de ignorar os números ficou depois do "random" e não antes...

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca o exemplo de código com 4x4. Outra coisa, vc precisa mesmo manter esse algoritmo? Existem outros que geram o quadrado mágico de uma uma forma muitro mais rapida e simples.

Comment: Vou editar.. é que infelizmente eu preciso desse jeito mesmo... os outros são normais.. e não atingem o objetivo.. só assim que atingiria o objetivo.. eu vou postar em 4x4.. aqui blz..

Comment: Tom, eu tava pensando aqui, realmente o que você disse, faz sentido, poderia mudar o algoritmo de como encontra o quadrado mágico, mas só que com o mesmo sistema de ter uma lista e poder ignorar certos números.. só mudar o algoritmo de como encontrar os quadrados mágicos, um jeito diferente desse de vetores...